# How to Use NLog and Log error to database in ASP.Net Core

Tags: nlog, error-logging, custom-error-handling

I am using NLog.web and Nlog.config . Able to log error to file . When try to log to database.
Getting target database cant be found.

Please help if any one using Nlog with asp.net core rc1  and logging error to database

My configuration look likes

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" internalLogFile="Nlog.log">
  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${logger}|${threadid}|${windows-identity:domain=false}--${message} ${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*" fileName="c:\psnet\myapplication.log"/>
    <target name="database" type="Database">
      <connectionString>
        Data Source=databaseservername;Initial Catalog=databasename;User Id=username;Password=password;
      </connectionString>
      <commandText>
        insert into system_logging(log_date,log_level,log_logger,log_message,log_machine_name, log_user_name, log_call_site, log_thread, log_exception, log_stacktrace) values(@time_stamp, @level, @logger, @message,@machinename, @user_name, @call_site, @threadid, @log_exception, @stacktrace);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}"/>
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}"/>
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
      <parameter name="@machinename" layout="${machinename}"/>
      <parameter name="@user_name" layout="${windows-identity:domain=true}"/>
      <parameter name="@call_site" layout="${callsite:filename=true}"/>
      <parameter name="@threadid" layout="${threadid}"/>
      <parameter name="@log_exception" layout="${exception}"/>
      <parameter name="@stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace}"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" appendTo="database"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I am able to write to file.. IN Nog internal file it showing error target database is unkown
Even when trying to write to event log showing same error
Target EventLog is unknown

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Your configuration will probably be wrong but we can't tell because you're not showing us anything.

Comment: I Have added complete configuration .Please have a look

Comment: EventLog on NetCore requires: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.WindowsEventLog/ . DatabaseTarget on NetCore requires: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/

Answer (score 3):

You need as the [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/) package

#### 1. Add dependency in project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-*"
 }
```

#### 2. Create nlog.config in root of your project file, see [NLog.config example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/03971763546cc70660529bbe28b282304adb7571/examples/aspnet-core-example/src/aspnet-core-example/nlog.config)

#### 3.  in startup.cs add in `Configure`

```
  using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
      loggerFactory.AddNLog();


      //needed for non-NETSTANDARD platforms: configure nlog.config in your project root
      env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
      ...
```

#### 4. Include NLog.config for publishing in project.json:

```
   "publishOptions": {
        "include": [
            "wwwroot",
            "Views",
            "appsettings.json",
            "web.config",
            "nlog.config"
        ]
    },
```

#### 5. Not working?

Enabled and check the [internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging)!

Comment: I want using `NLog` in.Net Core library, i do these steps as u said, but in library we dont have ` startup.cs `, so i try  `Configuration API` in :`https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API` instead of `env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");` but it doesnt work, do u have any idea about it? thanks

Comment: It's a console application?